# Wrong value when inserting into a linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to insert words into a hash table and it looks like it works but when I try to print the word inside the node (just to check if its still correct) I get a bogus value. When my code prompts for the word I said **'Hey'** and when it prompts for place I said **'5'**. The string that is printed out(which is supposed to be the word inside the node) is  **HH9[]A\A]A^A_f.** What is happening to the word inside the node and am I inserting the node correctly?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char word[20];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int main (void)
{
    node* table[10];
 
    char wrd[10];
    
    printf("Word to insert: ");
    fgets(wrd, 10, stdin);
    
    int place; 
    printf("Place to insert word: ");
    scanf("%d", &place);
    
    
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        
    if(n == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
        
    strcpy(n->word, wrd);
        
    if(table[place] == NULL)
    {
        n = table[place];
        n->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        n->next = table[place];
        
        n = table[place];
    }
    
    printf("Word inside node: %s \n" , n->word);
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code and tried to implement it on a larger scale but my while loop gives me a segfault. This is the function I put it in:

```
    FILE* dct = fopen ("/dictionaries/large", "r");
    char *wrd = NULL;
    
    while(fscanf(dct, "%s", wrd) != EOF)
    {

        int place = hash(wrd);
        
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        node *anchor = NULL;
        node *end = NULL;
        
        if(n == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        
        strcpy(n->word, wrd);

        n->next = NULL;

        if (!end)    //Initial state
            anchor = end = n;
        else        //Every following node.
            end = end->next = n;
        
        strcpy(n->word, wrd);
        
        n->next = table[place];

        table[place] = n;
        
        counter++;
    }
    
    return false;
```

It has to read from the dictionary file and load the word into memory(or a hash table).

Comment: You are accessing 'n' after setting it to the value of 'next', which is 'NULL' at this point.

Comment: The array `table` isn't initialized. All elements will have *indeterminate* values.

Comment: Also think about `n = table[place]`... Shouldn't the assignment be the opposite?

Comment: And there's really no need for the `if(table[place] == NULL)` check. All you need is the `else` case (once you fix the assignment).

Comment: I fixed the assignment and the word inside the node is correct now. How can I check if the word inside table[5] is correct?

Comment: If you absolutely need to have a table (which kinda defeats the point of having a linked list), you can just access `table[5]->word`.

Comment: So I can replace the whole if/else statement with ```n->next = table[place];
        
    table[place] = n;```

Comment: If you want a fixed size array, you can skip the entire `if/else` logic, the dynamic allocation and the `next` member of your structure. Simply make it an array of type `Node` and use offset calculations.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium this is just a small part of the actual code. I nee to insert a whole dictionary into a table to decrease the runtime of searching for a word . So I thought an array of linked lists will work better.

Comment: Well, I've posted a small example on how to allocate a single linked list. You can just scale that up, with `anchor` being your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked list is a linked list because it does not have a fixed size.
The `table` array is therefor superfluous.
What you need for your linked list to work is to remember the anchor and nothing more.

A small example:

```
Node *anchor = NULL;
Node *end = NULL;
Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));

node->next = NULL;

if (!end)    //Initial state
    anchor = end = node;
else        //Every following node.
    end = end->next = node;
```

At this point, you can still access the `node` you've just filled. Don't forget to iterate over your list later and `free` those allocations though.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't make any sense:

```
    if(table[place] == NULL)
    {
        n = table[place]; // since we know table[place] is null, that sets n to null!
        n->next = NULL;   // We just set n to NULL, we can't access n->next!
    }
    else
    {
        n->next = table[place]; // This sets n to a garbage value since table[place] was never assigned a value
   
        n = table[place]; // This leaks the value we malloc'ed. We were supposed to link it to the list!
    }
```